# INNER JOIN that creates too many rows

Tags: sql

I am using SQL and trying to join two tables. My "denominator" is the `ISIN` column (finance id number).

Currently, my code create a large amount of data with the following code instead of just join the two tables. I don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT *
FROM tablefinance AS fin
INNER JOIN tablefund AS fund ON fund.ISIN = fin.ISIN
WHERE fin.Buy_Date = '2023-02-16'
```

Table `fin` has 500 rows, table `fund` has 1000, but this code resulted in more than hundred thousand rows.

I don't understand why, maybe it is because I have too many columns? (more than forty in each table)

Here is some sample:

| NAV_Date | ISIN | ID_Security | Security_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-16 | XS2587965214 | 545585 | BNP |
| 2023-01-16 | XS2229000000 | 481234 | GOOGLE |
| 2023-01-16 | XS2301458741 | 758798 | APPLE |

| NAV_Date | Fund_name | ID_Position | ID_Security | ISIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-16 | Fund 1 | 100008 | 545585 | XS2587965214 |
| 2022-01-16 | Fund 1 | 199350 | 481234 | XS2229000000 |
| 2022-01-16 | Fund 1 | 115409 | 758798 | XS2301458741 |

Comment: Are you sure you get 2.5 million rows? The worst case is cross join which gives 500*1000=500k records. And, as usual, some sample data and desired output are highly welcome. By the way, INNER JOIN in the header and RIGHT JOIN in the code are different JOINS. Please amend

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I corrected it. In fact I had to stop the computation, it was very huge. I added some data.

Comment: If ISIN is not (the only) primary key in any of the two tables, it would result in returning more rows than expected by you. Although as Sergey already posted, the maximum would be 500k in your case.

Comment: where is the `sec` table in you query? We only see `tablefinance` and `tablefund`. The resulting row count is smaller or equal to row count of the largest table.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Pretty sure that you ISIN is not unique in at least one of tables! can you check it out?
`SELECT COUNT(SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted FROM tablefinance fin GROUP BY ISIN HAVING counted > 1)` . run this query for both tables it should return 0 in both or at least one table!

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH TABLEFINANCE(NAV_Date, ISIN ,ID_Security , Security_name)AS
(
   SELECT '2023-01-16'::DATE,'XS2587965214',    545585,'BNP' 
     UNION ALL 
   SELECT '2023-01-16','XS2229000000',  481234,     'GOOGLE'
    UNION ALL 
   SELECT '2023-01-16','XS2301458741',758798,'APPLE'
 ),
TABLEFUND(NAV_Date, Fund_name,ID_Position,ID_Security,  ISIN)AS
(
   SELECT '2022-01-16'::DATE,'Fund 1',  100008,     545585,     'XS2587965214'UNION ALL
   SELECT '2022-01-16',     'Fund 1',   199350,     481234,     'XS2229000000'UNION ALL
  SELECT    '2022-01-16',   'Fund 1',   115409,     758798,     'XS2301458741'
)
 SELECT FI.*,FU.*
 FROM TABLEFINANCE AS FI
 JOIN TABLEFUND AS FU ON FI.ISIN=FU.ISIN
```

With sample data you provided it is not possible to confirm your complain (query returns three records)
May be you need to enhance join condition to include also NAV_DATE like

```
 SELECT FI.*,FU.*
 FROM TABLEFINANCE AS FI
 JOIN TABLEFUND AS FU ON FI.ISIN=FU.ISIN AND FI.NAV_DATE=FU.NAV_DATE
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your sample data, it looks like these three columns are the correct keys to join:

```
NAV_Date, ISIN, ID_Security
```

So I would recommend the following query to join the tables:

```
SELECT
  * /* Also be careful about a regular * here, as it will display all columns of all joined tables. You possibly want something like fin.*, fund.Fund_Name */
FROM
  tablefinance AS fin
INNER JOIN
  tablefund AS fund
ON
  fund.ISIN = fin.ISIN AND
  fund.NAV_Date = fin.NAV_Date AND
  fund.ID_Security = fin.ID_Security
WHERE
  fin.Buy_Date = '2023-02-16'
```